# Silex form - Method error (POST/GET)

Tags: php, forms, http, twig, silex

I have a problem with the Silex form. (A simple to test).

Annotations come from the bundle: https://github.com/danadesrosiers/silex-annotation-provider

This is my function :

```
/**
     * @SLX\Route(
     *      @SLX\Request(method="GET", uri="add"),
     *      @SLX\Bind(routeName="departement.add")
     * )
     */
    public function add(Application $app, Request $request)
    {   
        $data = [];
        $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class, $data)
        ->add('nom_dep',null,array('label' => 'Nom :'))
        ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            dump("test");die();
            return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("departement.index"));
        }

        // display the form
        return $app['twig']->render('departement/new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

And this is my view :

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-horizontal form-condensed', 'role': 'form' } }) }}
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Création</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="{{ form.nom_dep.vars.id }}" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nom :</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                       {{ form_widget(form.nom_dep,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Créer" class="btn btn-info" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And the result of the form :

```
<form name="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-condensed" role="form">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Création</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_nom_dep" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nom :</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                       <input type="text" id="form_nom_dep" name="form[nom_dep]" required="required" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Créer" class="btn btn-info">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="CGhbs1VCxoJ1DFHkLKodt9bRaEZCH1JEoqYJh8TK7I8"></form>
```

But when I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
No route found for "POST /departement/add": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)
```

This is normal because my route is in GET method.
And if I change to POST, I can not display the view because it is the GET method.

Any help is welcome. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the documentation correctly, you should be able to register multiple request methods like this

```
/**
     * @SLX\Route(
     *      @SLX\Request(method="GET", uri="add"),
     *      @SLX\Request(method="POST", uri="add"),
     *      @SLX\Bind(routeName="departement.add")
     * )
     */
    public function add(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
```

<sub>*The @Request annotation associates a uri pattern to the controller method. If multiple @Request annotations are given, all modifiers will be applied to all @Requests unless they wrapped in a @Route annotation.*</sub>